# I want <form> to DOM

Tags: javascript

```html
<form id="search" action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Google 검색 또는 URL 입력">
</form>
```

literally I want to change  dynamically to DOM

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what do you ask but it seems like you want to dynamically add this element to DOM. 
For this, you can put this markup in a single line and wrap it in single quotes('').
var formElement = '  '

or you can just use es6 string literals(``).

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.